# Hibernate C3P0 - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, c3p0

When my Struts app on Glassfish queries for first time, such error occurs:

```
Severe: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources
Info: 2015-07-28 13:59:17 ERROR HibernateUtil:54 - Initial SessionFactory creation failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    [...]
```

I've tried to resolve this using [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-errorinitial-sessionfactory-creation-failed-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-commchangev2c3p0datasources/), but still same error occurs..

My dependencies I use to run this app:

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
                <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0-oracle-thin-extras</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mchange AND c3p0</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This app worked perfectly without Maven..

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Check whether the same version of JAR files used for compilation are exists in class path.

Comment: @LoganathanMohanraj most of the jars are without versions marks.. Even in MANIFEST there's no information about version...

Comment: Well. You must be knowing the JAR files used to compile your code. Use the same JAR files for running your code as well.

Comment: This project worked before I restructured this using Maven.. And C3P0 libraries are same as version I found in libs... Am I supposed to add C3P0 library to Glassfish Libs?

Comment: Try recompiling with JAR files in Maven repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved - I had to add c3p0-[version].jar to **Glassfish** libs directory under *domains/domain1/libs*

Answer (score 2):

In

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mchange AND c3p0</groupId>
   <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The `AND c3p0` is superfluous.

It should be

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
   <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or better yet, use the current production version

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
   <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Eehh I didn't want to write both separately.

Comment: There is no 'both separately'. "com.mchange" is the group id, "c3p0" is the artifact id, you just declare one dependency.

Comment: Oh Really?!.. I know it... Guess you didnt understand what I meant